# Javascript: Application not accessible http://hostname/Application/page.htm

Tags: javascript, redirect, ip, hostname

There is a issue I am facing in javascript redirection.

I have 2 pages in my application - **login.htm and main.htm**

So when the application starts using this **URI** ***http://hostname/Application/login.htm***

> However when I try and redirect to main page using following JS code
>
> $window.location.href = 'main.html';

URI generated is ***http://hostname/Application/main.htm*** But the redirect does not happen - there is no error logged.

**Please note that this redirect works fine when i use IP address instead of hostname.**

Comment: Just to make sure, You said you have two pages: "login.html" and "main.html" (no "index.html"). So why redirecting to "index.html"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that.. I wrote index mistakenly in the post.